# AVAsset video size (width * height)

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, avasset

I capture a screen record and output it to an file. And My mac is retina.

I get the file size by:

```
self.asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:_assetURL];

AVAssetTrack *track = [[self.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
self.vedioNaturalSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
```

but this size is in pixel, I want to get the size in point.

When I play the video in QuickTime, I found the initial window size in point not in pixel, but I can only get the size in pixel.

Does anybody know the approach, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code convert pixelToPoints

```
+(CGFloat)pixelToPoints:(CGFloat)px {
CGFloat pointsPerInch = 72.0; // see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point%5Fsize#Current%5FDTP%5Fpoint%5Fsystem
CGFloat scale = 1; // We dont't use [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] as we don't want the native pixel, we want pixels for UIFont - it does the retina scaling for us
float pixelPerInch; // aka dpi
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    pixelPerInch = 132 * scale;
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    pixelPerInch = 163 * scale;
} else {
    pixelPerInch = 160 * scale;
}
CGFloat result = px * pointsPerInch / pixelPerInch;
return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try this.  But I actually want to know if it exists a API to get the point of an asset.